# Reset Counter OnClick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code I am using to countdown from 15 after 15 secs passes it echoes "times over". The problem is if someone clicks twice there will be two counters in the same Div. I need the counter to reset if someone clicks on the button again.

```
function startCountDown(i, p, f) {
    // store parameters
    var pause = p;
    var fn = f;
    // make reference to div
    var countDownObj = document.getElementById("countDown");
    if (countDownObj == null) {
        // error
        alert("div not found, check your id");
        // bail
        return;
    }
    countDownObj.count = function (i) {
        // write out count
        countDownObj.innerHTML = i;
        if (i == 0) {
            // execute function
            fn();
            // stop
            return;
        }
        setTimeout(function () {
            // repeat
            countDownObj.count(i - 1);
        },
        pause);
    }
    // set it going
    countDownObj.count(i);
}

function myFunction() {
    alert("Time Over");
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="TimerTitle">Timer</div>    
<span id="countDown"></span>
<button onclick="startCountDown(15, 1000, myFunction);">
    Start Time
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the timeout as a global variable like so:

```
timer = setTimeout(function(){countDownObj.count(i - 1);},pause);
```

At the beginning of the function clear the timeout

```
clearTimeout(timer)
```

Code:

```
var timer;
function startCountDown(i, p, f) {
// store parameters
if(timer){clearTimeout(timer)}
var pause = p;
var fn = f;
// make reference to div
var countDownObj = document.getElementById("countDown");
if (countDownObj == null) {
    // error
    alert("div not found, check your id");
    // bail
    return;
}
countDownObj.count = function (i) {
    // write out count
    countDownObj.innerHTML = i;
    if (i == 0) {
        // execute function
        fn();
        // stop
        return;
    }
timer = setTimeout(function(){countDownObj.count(i - 1);},pause);
}
// set it going
countDownObj.count(i);
}

function myFunction() {
alert("Time Over");
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that you also have to set timer as a variable before the function. The code I have added to my answer works for me.

Comment: I see this has gotten a fair amount of views. Coming back to my work I just didn't want to use global variables. I saw quickly after this it wasn't a problem. ES6 though handle this much better.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` returns an **id** to the timer that can be used with `window.clearTimeout`. The simplest solution would be to create a global `timerId`

```
var timerId; 
...

function startCountDown(i, p, f) { 
    ...
    if (timerId) { window.clearTimeout(timerId); }
    timerId = window.setTimeout(...);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout